# How to ask for Runtime App Permissions on Pre Marshmallow Custom Android OS like Xiaomi, Lava, Cyanogen Mod?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have faced problems while getting Location data in OEM's Custom OS (Pre-Marshmallow i.e. Android Version < 6.0) with Permission Managers where the user can deny Location permission to the app.

Is there a way to detect that the permissions have been denied and also a way to ask for those permissions?

Comment: Ask the custom ROM developers and the device manufacturers. There are no standards here.

Comment: Did you find the way to ask for permission ? I am also looking for the same.